# How to get List of Opportunities with condition on OpportunityContactRole?

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to retrieve the list of Opportunities which have at least one OpportunityContactRole with role equal to test

Right now, I am doing the below query but it retrieves all the rows in the opportunity table..

```
[SELECT Id,
    (SELECT Id FROM OpportunityContactRoles WHERE Role = 'test')
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE IsClosed = TRUE AND IsWon = TRUE];
```

Is there any better alternative for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Which approach to use depends on what else you're trying to do.

## 1. Query from the child object:

```
[SELECT Id, OpportunityId
 FROM OpportunityContactRoles
 WHERE Opportunity.IsClosed = TRUE
    AND Opportunity.IsWon = TRUE
    AND Role = 'test']
```

You can then loop over these results to get unique Opportunity Ids.

## 2. Use a second sub-query in your WHERE clause:

```
[SELECT Id,
    (SELECT Id FROM OpportunityContactRoles WHERE Role = 'test')
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE IsClosed = TRUE AND IsWon = TRUE
    AND Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRoles WHERE Role = 'test')];
```

This approach filters the main query based on the records found in the sub-query.

Comment: As I need this query on the Opportunity Trigger 2nd Option is easy for me..Thanks